# local staging magento site redirecting to live site

Tags: magento, redirect, ubuntu, migration, staging

I followed [this tutorial](http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/06/03/how-to-install-magento-on-ubuntu/) to set up a local staging version of our magento site.  Locally it is running on an ubuntu & an apache server.

Everything seemed to work fine but when I point a browser at the staging site it redirects to the live site.

So far I've tried:

1. changing in the url entries in **mg_core_config_data** table in the local database
2. clearing the browser cache & cookies
3. Changing the **.htaccess file** to include `RewriteBase /localhost/`

None of these worked, I've read that the **app/etc/local.xml file** may have some settings that could be causing this, but I can't find them.

Should I add some kind of rewrite to the **.htaccess file** ???

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my **app/etc/local.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * Blah Blah
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Mon, 07 Oct 2013 06:25:58 -0500]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[de1v6an96abmo8kdhho2qbqrmcal3z0w]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[mg_]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[??????]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[??????]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[??????]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
     </global>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
     </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved!

The Redirect problem was due to **Magento cache**. I Simply deleted everything from the **var/** folder of my Magento site. After that I cleared my browser's cache/cookies for good measure & it worked!

Comment: saved my time perfect answer

Comment: More than that, clear your browser cache too. Mine was problem with browser cache. I cleared it. IT worked.

Answer (score 3):

for me, the problem was :

- local.xml updated
- List item
- secure/base_url and unsecure/base_url updated
- All copied properly
- var folder emptied

still redirecting to live website.

The file permission of the magento folder were 775, I changed it to 777 and voila.

Note that this has the usual security issue and a chown www-data:www-data would be preferable. My dev server does not need to be too secured so the 0777 simplifies a bit.

Answer (score 1):

We should always delete var/cache after moving to another server or doing any major change in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of permission.I solved it after setting permissions to folders.

```
sudo chown -R group:user .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \; && sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Please use `chmod` parameter, what is desired like `655,755` or whatever you need depends upon folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me finally what worked was

php shell/indexer.php --reindexall via ssh. It appears, quite logically so, that after the files have been copied over from a previous live installation the urls still point to the old store and hence have to be reindexed, in my case via  ssh.

Hope it works for others too !